# External Adata HDD stopped working

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, partition-recovery

My external HDD Adata Classic CH94 has stopped working. It is a 500 GB HDD with at least 270+ GB filled with TV shows, games, movies and images.

When I attached it, I got this message. The message displayed when I connect it:

[image]

I can't format it, I need the data. I also set it up for Windows ReadyBoost but it worked fine after a few days as well. It stopped working a week ago. Please help.

Comment: First of all, does the drive make any strange sounds or ticks? (if it does it is probably a hardware problem and you will need to get a new drive and recover from your backups). If it makes no strange sounds then try to get some more information from the drive. Get its status via [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) and add that. Consider removing the drive from its USB casing and mount it directly in a desktop. (That will make attempted recovery much easier as well as making a full backup of the damaged drive much faster - see ddrescue

Comment: No, I do not hear any noises of disk spinning. I don't think its a hardware error...

Answer (score 0):

Numerous data recovery tools exist.
PhotoRec
RStudio  rstudio.com
GetDataBack for NTFS   http://runtime.org
http://www.r-studio.com/

You need a new external/internal hdd all recovery tools want a new hard drive to put their files on during the recovery process.

Run one of the many recovery tools and see what it can see.
As @Hennes mentions if you here strange clicking sounds you could have a head crash or worse.

If you can manage to open the external hard drive and attach it to a SATA or IDE port things will go much faster.  USB is limited to approx 30mb/s and SATA can go higher than your hard drive.  However you should get at least 2x-3x faster than USB 2.

Also if the data is really important a service like DriveSavers.com will gladly charge you as much as $1000-$2000 to get it back.